# How to use Unix Shell to show only the first n columns and last n columns?

Tags: awk, sed, csv, cut

I have many csv files. The original design was supposed to have five columns.

I just found out that the middle column of the csv file has a string with arbitrary number of commas in it and it is not quoted properly. This leads to rows with arbitrary number of columns.

How do I get just the first two and last two columns of these csv files?

Since the number of commas can change from row to row I need a way to specify first two and last two columns.

Comment: Please tell me the middle column is enclosed in quote marks.  If it is not, tell whoever created these files they did it wrong.

Comment: If the columns are properly quoted, then you can use a language (like [perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) or [python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) or even [awk](https://github.com/geoffroy-aubry/awk-csv-parser)) that has a CSV parsing library.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205431/parse-a-csv-using-awk-and-ignoring-commas-inside-a-field

Comment: Yeah it wasn't quoted. The worst part is that column was not needed at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{print $1, $2, $(NF-1), $NF}'  < input
```

---

More generally (per the Question's title), to print the first and last `n` columns of the input -- without checking to see whether that means printing some columns twice --

```
awk -v n=2 '{ 
  for(i=1; i <= n && i <= NF; i++)
      printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
    for(i=NF-n+1; i <= NF && i >= 1; i++)
      printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
    printf "%s", ORS
  }' < input
```

(using `-F` as needed for the delimiter)

Comment: you dont have to use a redirect

Comment: That’s correct. It’s a habit I’m trying to form after seeing advice in that direction from other U&L members here. It means that the shell reports errors/failures instead of the utility — more consistency. It also prevents the utility from running if the IO redirection fails.

Answer (score 1):

perl:

```
echo a,b,X,X,X,X,c,d | perl -F, -slane 'print join ",", @F[0..$n-1, -$n..-1]' -- -n=2
```

```
a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed too

```
sed -E 's/(([^,]*,){2}).*((,[^,]*){2})/\1\3/;s/,,/,/'
```